# ios 6 - Post to Facebook in app not working on device

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, facebook, ios6

I have a button that brings up the Facebook ui to make a post, but it doesn't do anything on the device. It works fine in the simulator, but performs no action at all on the phone.

Not sure what I can do to figure out the problem -

Here is my ViewController.h

```
- (IBAction)postToFacebook:(id)sender;
```

ViewController.m

```
- (IBAction)postToFacebook:(id)sender {
    if ([SLComposeViewController isAvailableForServiceType:SLServiceTypeFacebook]) {
        SLComposeViewController *controller = [SLComposeViewController composeViewControllerForServiceType:SLServiceTypeFacebook];
        [controller setInitialText:@"Posted from IOS App Test -- It works!"];
        [self presentViewController:controller animated:YES completion:Nil];
    }}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You code is working on simulator because isAvailableForServiceType always returns 1 in Simulator. In device you need to setup a facebook account from settings.

Or better just remove this check

```
[SLComposeViewController isAvailableForServiceType:SLServiceTypeFacebook]
```

With this along with the post sheet an OS alert will appear to notify that account setup is required to post.

Comment: Okay; I've removed that and it does work on the phone. Shouldn't it have worked anyways since I DO have a Facebook account on the device?

Comment: Can you confirm 1) You have facebook account setup done in your iPhone's setting. 2) postToFacebook is getting called on device (put a break point there. 3) there is no isAvailableForServiceType check & self is not nil.

Comment: I think I initially misunderstood; it seems like there is a difference between logging into Facebook in settings and simply downloading the app and logging into that. I logged in through settings on the phone; hadn't done that previously. Regardless though, I can see how initiating the post on the isavailableforservice condition isn't the best idea for what I'm doing. Thanks